# Problems with getText() from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

http://pastebin.com/babqrrqa

Like the title says, i have problems with getting the text from a EditText.

My app crashes when reads this line :

**String value = aux.getText().toString();**, probably because aux.getText() is null still i have setText("lol"), at this method

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
    switch (item.getItemId()) {  
    case R.id.adicionar:  
        //Toast.makeText(this, "This is the Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);

         LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         LinearLayout dialerLayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input, null);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            dialerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);


        alert.setView(dialerLayout);



        alert.setPositiveButton("Adicionar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


                aux = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cadeira);
                aux.setText("lol");
                String value = aux.getText().toString();
                //String value2="TESTE";

            lista.add(value);
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        alert.show();



    return true;  
    default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the "aux" is null.

As I suppose from your code the "cadeira" EditText is in the LinearLayout that you inflate. But when you execute "findViewByById" it searches the main layout. Thus you should try:

```
aux = (EditText) dialerLayout.findViewById(R.id.cadeira);
```

Comment: Exactly, the problem was that!

Very Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the `.toString()`! The result of the `getText()` will be a string already so the `toString()` might cause it to crash.

Comment: if i leave `.toString()` the result of aux.getText() is a Editable object, instead of a String.

Comment: that is strange as I've always thought of getText() as returning a string. hmm. Then i'm not sure really, sorry.

Comment: No problem! Look up, is the answer!

Comment: @ruhatch: Calling the `toString()` method on a non-null `String` just returns itself, nothing can crash here.

Answer (score 0):

there might be **human error with declaring or initializing "aux",** though you haven't shown the exactly error log wording,
if you can detail it more, this will fix the prob faster.